# Python - unpacking nested json

Tags: python, arrays, json, bigdata

I have the following problem: I can not unpack a "Nested JSON"

To obtain this dataset, I used the following code:

```
 a = pd.json_normalize(variavel, max_level=5)
 a
```

[Nested JSON](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EsiUK.png)

Take a look at the last column "node.phases_history". That's the nested json. No matter how many levels I use, I not being able to unpack it.

So, I tried to normalize the column with the nested JSON.

```
pd.json_normalize(a['node.phases_history'])
```

And it also does not work, again, no matter how many levels in the max_level I set.

And, when I try it:

```
pd.json_normalize(a['node.phases_history'][1])
```

[Nested JSON_2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NPPij.png)

It works, but only for a single registry.

Anyone knows can I solve it, and how I can automate it, no matter how much columns are added?

Comment: Have you tried to use it on whole object? 
a = pd.json_normalize(variavel)

Comment: Have you tried to use zero as the max_level parameter? From the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html)

Comment: You would increase your chance of an answer if you would include the actual JSON file sample.